# Swapping elements in an array of structs using pointers c++

Tags: c++

I see a couple similar questions but they don't have answers for my specific case. I simply need to swap the location of two elements in an array of structs, but everything I've tried so far will only copy one or the other. I believe the issue lies in the swap function.

I need do do this without the use of standard library functions. Here's what I have:

```
struct RentalCar {
    int year;
    char make[STRLEN];
    char model[STRLEN];
    float price;
    bool available;
};

void carCopy(RentalCar *dest, RentalCar *source) { // dest = source
    dest->year = source->year;
    myStrCpy(dest->make, source->make);            // copy c-strings
    myStrCpy(dest->model, source->model);
    dest->price = source->price;
    dest->available = source->available;
}

void carSwap(RentalCar *car1, RentalCar *car2) {
    RentalCar *carTemp = car1;
    carCopy(carTemp, car2);   // tried different orders, only copy no swap
    carCopy(car2, car1);
}

char *myStrCpy(char *dest, const char *source) {    // copy cstring
    char *origin = dest;                            // non iterated address
    while (*source || *dest) {
        *dest = *source;
        dest++;
        source++;
    }
    return origin;  // could return void instead
}
```

Comment: `carSwap()` needs to create an actual object, not just a pointer.    Since `carTemp` points at `car1`, the function is equivalent to `carCopy(car1, car2); carCopy(car2, car1);` whih has the net effect of setting the contents of `car1` and `car2` to the original values of `car2`.     To fix, create an object not a pointer, then do three copies (e.g. `car1` to the `carTemp`, `car2` to `car1`, then `carTemp` to `car2`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing shallow copies with deep copies:

```
void carSwap(RentalCar *car1, RentalCar *car2) {
    RentalCar *carTemp = car1; // shallow copy
    carCopy(carTemp, car2);   // deep copy: overrides carTemp AND car1
    carCopy(car2, car1); // car1 and car2 already have the same values
    // original car1 data is lost
}
```

Because `carSwap` is given `RentalCar*` (and not `RentalCar**`) we can't change the user's pointer, so we must stick to deep copies.

We ***could*** do this (and still use the other functions):

```
void carSwap(RentalCar *car1, RentalCar *car2) {
    RentalCar carTemp = *car1;
    carCopy(car1, car2);
    carCopy(car2, &carTemp);
}
```

But we don't need the other functions. We can just do this:

```
void carSwap(RentalCar *car1, RentalCar *car2) {
    RentalCar carTemp = *car1;
    *car1 = *car2;
    *car2 = carTemp;
}
```

Comment: That actually does work, I must've been doing something out of order the first time I tried to shallow copy it

Comment: The array only has 5 elements and its for a school assignment, I'm not worried about efficient use of memory here. But out of curiosity, how would I do this without creating a new temporary object?

Comment: Here pointers are useful as they're just an address, so the making/copying of pointers requires no construction:

RentalCar * array[5]; // an array of pointers to structures
// ...
// add objects to your array
//...
// The swapping will be similar to before:
RentalCar * tmp = array[i];
array[i] = array[j];
array[j] = tmp;

Answer (score 1):

In `carSwap`, `carTemp` is a pointer pointing to the same memory location as `car1`. The line

```
carCopy(carTemp, car2);   // tried different orders, only copy no swap
```

overwrites `car1` with `car2`.

Change `carSwap` to this:

```
void carSwap(RentalCar *car1, RentalCar *car2) {
    RentalCar carTemp;
    carCopy(&carTemp, car2);
    carCopy(car2, car1);
    carCopy(car1, &carTemp);
}
```

Comment: I see the problem, what's the solution? I tried creating a new carTemp object but it just crashes on the function call.